# p:accordionPanel poll on first tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I disabled `<p:poll>` by default with `autoStart="false"` .
Now i have a dialog opened by commandButton with this example code :

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>

        <p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" oncomplete="PF('sampleDialog').show();PF('w_poll').start();"/>

        <p:dialog header="Sample Dialog" height="300" width="400" widgetVar="sampleDialog" resizable="false" onHide="PF('w_poll').stop();">
            <p:accordionPanel>
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="PF('w_poll').start();"/>
                <p:tab title="First">
                    <h:panelGroup id="firstGroup">
                        <p:poll interval="1"
                                id="firstPoll"
                                widgetVar="w_poll"
                                update="firstLabel"
                                async="true"
                                autoStart="false"
                                global="false"
                                listener="#{firstCounter.init}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{firstCounter.number}" id="firstLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Second">
                    <h:panelGroup id="secondGroup">
                        <p:poll interval="3"
                                id="secondPoll"
                                widgetVar="w_poll"
                                update="secondLabel"
                                async="true"
                                autoStart="false"
                                global="false"
                                listener="#{secondCounter.init}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{secondCounter.number}" id="secondLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Third">
                    <h:panelGroup id="thirdGroup">
                        <p:poll interval="5"
                                id="thirdPoll"
                                widgetVar="w_poll"
                                update="thirdLabel"
                                async="true"
                                autoStart="false"
                                global="false"
                                listener="#{thirdCounter.init}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{thirdCounter.number}" id="thirdLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
            </p:accordionPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Note :** you can see poll started on dialog show and stopped on hide .
this is my beans :

```
public abstract class AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    private int number;

    public void counter(int sleepTime) {
        sleep(sleepTime);
        this.number = number + 1;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    private static void sleep(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now implement three bean with this abstract :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class FirstCounter extends AbstractBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        counter(1000);
    }
}
```

and another :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SecondCounter extends AbstractBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        counter(3000);
    }
}
```

and another :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ThirdCounter extends AbstractBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        counter(5000);
    }
}
```

I have two problem :
1) first tab of accordion panel not started counter after dialog opened .
2) change tab event not work . i want to start counter of this same tab .

Comment: You cannot have multiple widget vars with the same value. That causes problems

Comment: So, what is your idea?

Comment: How about assigning different widgetvars?

Comment: But how can update that? How use p:Ajax?

Comment: Why are you updating tabs that are not visible? And why poll when you can push. Keep track of which tab is currently visible and only update the contents of that tab.

Comment: can you give me example code ?

Comment: Example code of what? Push is a totally unrelated question if you want help with that. And adding different widgetVars is trivial to me. So I fail to see what code we should provide.